# Run a script in a new terminal window

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, terminal

I am looking to run a script that is separate from my parent script in another terminal window while keeping the current window usable.

The reasoning behind this is I wish to allow the user to be able to run a watch script that will monitor directory changes as they are made.

this is my function for this

```
function watchFunction ()
{
  ./watch.sh &
}
```

However this only continues to run in the current window in the background.

I cannot use or install any of the following due to my linux distribution:
genone-terminal ; xterm ; screen ; konsole ; terminal or any other installable tools!

Any advice would be great as I am just starting out with bash scripting!

Comment: This is something that is specific to your terminal emulator. For example, `xterm -e /path/to/script`. Which terminal emulator are you using? (And what distro?)

Comment: @Sparhawk when I echo $TERM it says xterm is currently not installed and to install it. The distro is: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

Comment: `$TERM` [is not](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html) your terminal emulator. (e.g. I get `xterm-256color` even though I'm running Terminator.) What application are you actually launching to start the emulator? Also, you should be able to install any of those alternatives in Mint.

Comment: @Sparhawk the terminal I am using is the /bin/bash terminal but I also have Xfce Terminal. To start the terminal I press ctrl alt + T which brings up the /bin/bash terminal. Also the installing is not the issue unfortunately, its other constraints that are restricting me from installing them.

Comment: `/bin/bash` is the shell, not the terminal. I've posted an answer based on xfce4-terminal.

Comment: If any of the answers solved the problem, please up accept it by clicking the tick on the left, and also upvote useful answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to watch the output from the script, you can redirect the output from your script to a file and then watch that file in another window:

```bsh
# Run the script and log all output to a file
./watch.sh &> /var/log/watch.log &

# Watch the file, possibly in another terminal window
tail -f /var/log/watch.log
```

In my experience, this behavior (writing to a log file) is pretty typical. I don't recall ever having used a command-line application that started spawning other terminal windows.

That said, if you really want to open a new terminal window from the command-line then that will depend on the terminal application. There is a good post about this on the AskUbuntu StackExchange site:

- [Run command on another(new) terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401009/command-to-open-new-terminal-window-from-the-current-terminal)

In particular see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485011/368510). For example, for the Gnome terminal you might use a command such as the following:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./watch.sh; bash"
```

If you want to programmatically determine which terminal application is being used, you might want to refer to the following AskUbuntu post:

- [How can I get the name of the current terminal from command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476641/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-terminal-from-command-line)

The accepted solution there defines the following function:

```bsh
which_term(){
    term=$(perl -lpe 's/\0/ /g' \
           /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getactivewindow))/cmdline)

    ## Enable extended globbing patterns
    shopt -s extglob
    case $term in
        ## If this terminal is a python or perl program,
        ## then the emulator's name is likely the second 
        ## part of it
        */python*|*/perl*    )
         term=$(basename "$(readlink -f $(echo "$term" | cut -d ' ' -f 2))")
         version=$(dpkg -l "$term" | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
         ;;
        ## The special case of gnome-terminal
        *gnome-terminal-server* )
          term="gnome-terminal"
        ;;
        ## For other cases, just take the 1st
        ## field of $term
        * )
          term=${term/% */}
        ;;
     esac
     version=$(dpkg -l "$term" | awk '/^ii/{print $3}')
     echo "$term  $version"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments, you are using xfce4-terminal. From its [man page](https://man.cx/xfce4-terminal(1)), you can see the following option

```
−x, −−execute
Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal
```

Hence, you could simply prepend this to `./watch.sh`, i.e.

```
function watchFunction ()
{
  xfce4-terminal -x ./watch.sh &
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made that in a script I did. You need to launch a terminal window before executing the command.

```
xterm -e sh -c path/yo/your/script &;
```

In the script I wrote, I use something like this:

```
terminal="xterm"

run () {
    cmd="$terminal -e sh -c $1"
    [ -n "$1" ] && (eval "$cmd") > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}

run $VISUAL example/file/name
```

That will launch a terminal that will execute your program on it.
It will also prevent the first terminal to get filled with stderr/stdout messages from the new window.

Just replace the `terminal` variable to the one you use/like.